# when to use "get down to business" and "swing into action"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

In what situations we can use the two phrasal verbs "swing into action"         and "get down to business".If they are quite different in their meanings then what are the suitable examples to explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They convey similar meanings, the idea is to start doing your work immediately or energetically.

[***get down to business*** and get down to work:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+down+to+business)

> to begin to get serious; to begin to negotiate or conduct business.
>
> - *All right, every one. Let's get down to business. There has been enough chitchat. When the president and vice president arrive, we can get down to business.*

***[swing into action:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/swing+into+action)***

> Energetically start doing something, as in
>
> - *Come on, let's swing into action before the others arrive. **This idiom uses swing in the sense of "move vigorously."***

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)